# Vim with Ultisnips and bracket-matching (auto-pairs) mapped to the same key

Tags: vim, ultisnips

I use vim  mainly for latex. The main reason why I do it is actually Ultisnips, which greatly reduces the number of symbols that I need to type in latex.
Alongside it, I use auto-pairs, which matches brackets for me.
One small gripe that I have with this setup is that I cannot use tab in order to both expand a snippet and jump outside of a pair of brackets - the relevant options are:

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = '<tab>'
let g:UltisnipsJumpForwardTrigger = '<tab>'
let g:AutoPairsShortcutJump = '<tab>'
```

The behavior that I would like is to expand a snippet if one is available, otherwise jump out of the bracket. But that does not work by default. Is there anything I can do, like some kind of conditional key mapping?

I have tried other solutions, like implementing bracket matching in Ultisnips for example, but never with satisfactory results.

Yes, I could simply use another key, but using tab for both would be the most convenient.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with [user functions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#user-functions), utilizing the [return values](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/96026a4df27899b9e4029dd3b2977ad2ed819caf/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L253) of the UltiSnips `Trigger` functions. Since you have everything mapped to the same key, I'll create an example using the combined UltiSnips function, [`ExpandSnippetOrJump`](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/96026a4df27899b9e4029dd3b2977ad2ed819caf/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L272), which sets the global variable `ulti_expand_or_jump_res` to `0` if it could neither expand a snippet nor jump to the next one.

So you'll define a function (cheekily named `Ulti_Pairs()`) with:

```
function! Ulti_Pairs()
    call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippetOrJump()
    if g:ulti_expand_or_jump_res == 0
        call AutoPairsJump()
    endif
endfunction
```

Then you'll set your mapping (you shouldn't need your other ones after this):

```
inoremap <Tab> <ESC>:call Ulti_Pairs()<CR>a
```

So to walk through what this is doing, when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> Vim will call your custom function, which in turn calls `ExpandSnippetOrJump()`. If that function, returns anything else but `0` (meaning there was something to expand or jump to in UltiSnips) it won't do anything more. But on a return value of `0`, it'll call the `AutoPairsJump()` function.

Comment: I tried it out - unfortunately, it does not work. More precisely, expanding snippets works, but not jumping - neither with UltiSnips nor with auto-pairs. I don't really know vimscript, but trying to follow your logic: the custom function returns `g:ulti_expand_or_jump_res`, which is never changed, but is what is returned by the custom function. Am I missing something here?

Comment: As I mentioned in the first paragraph, the function `UltiSnips#ExpandSnippetOrJump()`, rather than properly returning a value, sets a global variable instead. So if that function is able to expand or jump, it'll set `g:ulti_expand_or_jump_res` to something other than `0`. It's set before the function because that's how UltiSnip's example usage did it, and I figured don't fix what ain't broke. You can debug that the variable is being set by adding some form of `echo` in the function, which should hopefully be a value that you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks. As I said, I know next to nothing about vimscript. I tried adding an `echo  g:ulti_expand_or_jump_res` before and after `call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippetOrJump()`, which returned 0 as expected when called on its own. However, when I pressed tab, regardless if there was something to expand or not, simply nothing happened, and nothing was echoed. So maybe something is wrong with the remap?

Comment: Maybe, but it shouldn't be. Let's troubleshoot in a [chat room I created](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206378/conversation-about-ultisnips); comments shouldn't be used for extended discussion